# MERN - How to access nested data in the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

My model looks like this :

```
coverPhoto: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
images: [{ 
  type: String 
}],
location: {
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  city: { type: String, required: true },
  postalCode: { type: Number, required: true },
  country: { type: String, required: true }
},
```

I seeded some data and it appears correctly in the database as :

```
"coverPhoto": "/images/SUSI.jpg",
"images": [
    "/images/SUSI1.jpg",
    "/images/SUSI2.jpg",
    "/images/SUSI3.jpg"
],
"location": {
    "address": "AM PICHELSSEE",
    "city": "BERLIN",
    "postalCode": 13595,
    "country": "Germany"
},
```

Now trying to access it in the frontend :

```
      <Col>
        <Image src={renting.coverPhoto} alt={renting.name} fluid />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Image src={renting.images[0]} alt={renting.name} fluid />
      </Col>
```

I added coverPhoto for reference because everything works fine with it.
But when I try to access images[0],[1](https://codesandbox.io/live/gxxr38l),[2] I get this error :

**EDIT**: I displayed the wrong error for the imput above.

The error is :
Cannot read property 0 of undefined.

When I try to access {renting.location.address} I get the same error that 'Cannot read property "address" of undefined'

When I console log inside the rentingActions, everything is fine.
When I console.log(data), I get the correct output.

console.log(data.images[0]) ==> /images/SUSI1.jpg
console.log(data.location.address) ==> AM PICHELSSEE

So I guess my question is, why can't I access nested objects ? Is it a syntax error ?
Link to my  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/gxxr38l)

Comment: 404 is the http status code for "not found". It seems like you tried to GET the resource at URL `/images/SUSI1.jpg,/images/SUSI2.jpg,/images/SUSI3.jpg`. And I guess you wanted to make three seperate requests.

Comment: You're right that the problem does come from there. That's actually the error I get when I call {renting.images}, which makes sense. 
When I call {renting.images[0]} I get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
Does the issue come from my routing ?

Comment: const getRentingById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const renting = await Renting.findById(req.params.id)

  if (renting) {
    res.json(renting)
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Listing not found')
  }
})

Comment: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" means `renting.images` is `undefined`. Now it's a good time to provide more context. Maybe a working example (easily done via codesandbox)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/gxxr38l
Not a working example since I can't connect to the DB but a basic version of my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem came from my reducer :

I was getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead" when I tried to access {renting.location}. So I realized the mistake came from my reducer :

Old version :

```
export const rentingDetailsReducer = (state = { renting: {} }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
case RENTING_DETAILS_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true, ...state } 
case RENTING_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, renting: action.payload }
case RENTING_DETAILS_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
default:
  return state }}
```

I had to specify in the state that 'location' was an object and 'images' an array.
Solution :

```
export const rentingDetailsReducer = (state = { renting: { location: {}, images: [] } }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
case RENTING_DETAILS_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true, ...state } 
case RENTING_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, renting: action.payload }
case RENTING_DETAILS_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
default:
  return state }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend gets the data, try to access it with a full url like this

```js
const image1=`http://yourhostname/yourImageFolder/{renting.images[0]}`;
//or 
const image1=`http://yourhostname:yourPort/yourImageFolder/{renting.images[0]}`;

//or identify the image folder locally then make the url
const image1 = `../imageFolder/{renting.images[0]}`;
```

Then you can put the `src` wherever you need, `src={image1}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where have you put your image url and how are you getting it but if you play around with the code below i think it will solve your problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [imgList, setImgList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
      );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setImgList(response.data);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {imgList
        ? imgList.map((e) => {
            return <img src={e.url} alt={e.title} />;
          })
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Explanation: a imgList state is declared and initialize with empty array.inside the useEffect hook i define an async function fetchData because useEffect hook is synchronous and inside the fetchData function i make a axios request.If the response is ok update the imgList state with response data.Inside the app function return i map the imgList url if imgList is not empty.

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-rain-r8w5l?file=/src/App.js:0-633)

Comment: I'm not sure if I can directly apply this example since the image array in embeded in a whole lot of data. Sorry I'm still quite new to this, here's a basic version of what my project looks like : https://codesandbox.io/live/gxxr38l

Comment: So to be clear,  {renting.coverPhoto} displays the cover photo, {renting.images} is defined but gives a wrong url obviously (/images/SUSI1.jpg,/images/SUSI2.jpg,/images/SUSI3.jpg) 
But {renting.images[i]} is undefined...

Comment: sorry look like i couldn't help you,reat-redux is beyond my understanding i am more familiar with context hook for state management

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of inconsistencies in my questions, I can access it in other files but not this one. I'll look for the mistake on my side, thanks for trying !